# Double integral, graphic sketch

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Will someone help me with this exercise?

If $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and
$$
\iint_D f(x,y)dxdy
 =\int_{-2}^0 \left[ \int_{x^2}^{6+x}f(x,y)dy\right]dx
 +\int_0^1\left[ \int_{x^2}^{6-5x}f(x,y)dy\right]dx.$$

1. Make a graphic sketch of the $D$ set.
2. Reverse the order of integration.

[image: picture]

Comment: $D$ is formed by a parabola and 2 lines.

Comment: Doing the sketch would be a nice excercise. Then you would need an "inverse" parametrisation of the inner integral bounds. Maybe you will have some ideas after doing the sketch?